# Alternative to Gloobus in Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, software-rec

In Ubuntu, I can use gloobus preview, which can view or run almost any file type just selecting the file and pressing space. Is there an alternative to gloobus for Windows which will be integrated in Windows explorer?

Answer (score 0):

[maComfort](http://rafaelklaus.com/macomfort/) looks pretty promising. I'll check it out when I get home, but it looks like what you need.